# ¿Cómo agregar una acción a un arreglo de Botones en Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, eventos, array

Asi como en Java es:

```
boton[x].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    }
});
```

Quisiera saber como se hace pero en Visual Basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira Alexis, para establecer un evento de la forma programada necesitaras hacer uso de un **Handler**

Por ejemplo:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim boton As New Button
    boton.Text = "Dime algo bueno"
    boton.Width = 200
    boton.Height = 50
    boton.Location = New Point(160, 20)
    AddHandler boton.Click, AddressOf Me.holaMundo
    Me.Controls.Add(boton)
End Sub

Private Sub holaMundo(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim hola As New Label
    hola.Name = "holaM"
    hola.Text = "Hola mundo!"
    hola.Location = New Point(210, 130)
    Me.Controls.Add(hola)
End Sub
End Class
```

Defini un boton nuevo y sus propiedades (texto, ancho, alto, posicion y evento) en el constructor. Deberas crear un metodo para definir la accion que va a realizar cuando se de clic en dicho boton. Cuando ya lo hayas definido, simplemente añades un **handler**, junto al metodo que el boton va a usar al momento que se le de clic:

> AddHandler boton.Click, AddressOf Me.holaMundo

Y ya esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu caso, como es un array de botones... tendrias que definir sus propiedades haciendo uso de un ciclo for. (obviamente)

Comment: Me funcionó a la perfección, pero si le pongo botones[x].addActionListener(this); también me funciona ¿Cuál sería la diferencia o es el uso incorrecto? gracias :)